# Is PackageManager.getComponentEnabledSettings() persistent between cold starts?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-package-managers

If I use the code below to disable a static BroadcastReceiver defined in AndroidManifest.xml, will it be re-enabled after a reboot? It doesn't appear to be but the docs don't say whether it should.

```
final ComponentName compName =
        new ComponentName(context,
        MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is PackageManager.getComponentEnabledSettings() persistent between cold starts?

Yes. It will be reset on an application uninstall/reinstall. It will be reset if you reset it yourself with `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. It'll be reset if something with superuser privileges resets it (e.g., the device might have some manager app for controlling `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`). And I'm not sure what happens on an app upgrade, as I haven't tried that scenario. Otherwise, it should stay persistent.

> If I use the code below to disable a static BroadcastReceiver defined in AndroidManifest.xml, will it be re-enabled after a reboot?

No.