# How setComponentEnabledSetting works?

Tags: android, android-service

I have enabled service in my AndroidManifest.xml. And I want to disable it from my code:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
    serviceName, 
    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

If I disable the service like above, will it be disabled forever? Or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, settings are persistent *until* reinstall (delete application, install again) or new value is set again with `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. Additionally, as a border case, someone with super-user privileges can reset your app.

Please read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949754/is-packagemanager-getcomponentenabledsettings-persistent-between-cold-starts) answer for details.

Answer (score 8):

It will be disabled until you enable it or the user uninstalls your app.

Comment: The `setComponentEnabledSetting` can be used only for the current app, right? It can't enable/disable anything of other apps, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Correct on both counts, barring some glaring security flaw. I also cannot rule out the possibility that device owner apps might have extra capabilities here. Plus, while a rooted app would not necessarily be able to simply call that method and affect other apps, they may be able to accomplish the same thing by other means.

Comment: Thank you. You probably mean by the same means of adb? I wonder what's the command via adb. Do you know? I remember there are (or were) apps to control what's starting on boot (which I think it's a bad idea, usually). Do you know what they use? I haven't even tried them.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "You probably mean by the same means of adb?" -- sorry, I do not know what options `adb` might offer here. "Do you know what they use?" -- no, sorry.